# how to add a character to a string in R

Tags: r

I have something like this:

```
text <- "abcdefg"
```

and I want something like this:

```
"abcde.fg"
```

how could I achieve this without assigning a new string to the vector `text` but instead changing the element of the vector itself? Finally, I would like to randomly insert the dot and actually not a dot but the character element of a vector.

Comment: To clarify: you cannot do this. You always need to create a new object (this isn’t true in all languages but in some, and in particular in R).

Comment: another option `text <- "abcdefg"; regmatches(text, gregexpr('(?<=^.{5})', text, perl = TRUE)) <- '.'; text`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can try with `sub` to capture the first 5 characters as a group (`(.{5})`) followed by one or more characters in another capture group (`(.*)`) and then replace with the backreference of first group (`\\1`) followed by a `.` followed by second backreference (`\\2`).

```
sub("(.{5})(.*)", "\\1.\\2", text)
#[1] "abcde.fg"
```

NOTE: This solution is direct and doesn't need to `paste` anything together.

Answer (score 10):

Also, `substring` with `paste` will work:

```
paste(substring(text, c(1,6), c(5,7)), collapse=".")
"abcde.fg"
```

The `substring` function accepts vector start-stop arguments and "splits" the string at the desired locations. We then can `paste` these elements together and with the collapse argument.

Without relying on the vector arguments, we could use the newer and recommended `substr` function:

```
paste(c(substr(text, 1, 5), substr(text, 6,7)), collapse=".")
[1] "abcde.fg"
```

Note that as mentioned by konrad-rudolph, this will create a copy of the vector.

Comment: The way I understand the documentation, `substring` only exists for S compatibility, and going forward `substr` should be used instead. However, this isn’t clear.

Comment: That is more or less my reading. The one additional advantage of `substring` is that that `substr` does not take vector start and stop arguments.

Comment: Yeah, and `substr` requires a `stop` argument (although the default for `susbtring` is insane, it should be a safe value that is *never* passed). I’m not sure why `substr` exists at all, to be honest … `substring` actually seems superior.