# Error adding and deleting characters from each element in a set of strings in R

Tags: r, string

I'm trying to delete the first 7 characters of each string in a set of strings. I've been following akrun's wonderful answer here ([how to add a character to a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38704603/how-to-add-a-character-to-a-string-in-r)). This is the command I've been using but it's returning an error:

```
backup_mouse_CTRL <- sub("(.{7})(.*)", "\\2", mouse_CTRL)


"Error in as.character.default(x) : no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector"
```

Is there an error in what I've written? Could you also help me a lot if someone could help me *add* these seven characters to every string in a list as well ("mm10---")? It would really help me for a later step in my analysis.

I've been trying to figure out how to paste a bit of my dataset here to allow for a reproducible example but my data is a Seurat object (useful for RNA-seq analysis in Biology) and the raw data is many gigabytes large. Because of that, I'm sorry I haven't been able to paste any data here.

I apologize if this question is basic - I have reviewed other similarly phrased questions and tried to integrate them into what I'm doing but I haven't had much luck unfortunately.

Comment: I trial the code with some random example and it work just fine - May you share a reproducible example of your code? - It seem that the mouse_CTRL is different type of object - may you share output of `class(mouse_CTRL)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your question @SinhNguyen! My computer crashed soon after I posted this so I'm not quite sure what the class of "mouse_CTRL" was but @jay.sf's answer down below turned out to work as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `substring`, in combination with `paste0`. If you want to replace each string individually, use `mapply`, else `sapply`:

```
mapply(\(x, y) paste0(y, substring(x, 8)), s, r)
#   AAAABDBBADCDCD   AABDBBCCAACDAC   AADBDDCBABDBCC 
# "ZYYZXXYACDABAA" "ZYXXXXXADDBADB" "YZXYXZYDCDADAD" 

sapply(s, \(x, r) paste0(r, substring(x, 8)), r='XXXXXXX')
#   AAAABDBBADCDCD   AABDBBCCAACDAC   AADBDDCBABDBCC 
# "XXXXXXXBADCDCD" "XXXXXXXCAACDAC" "XXXXXXXBABDBCC"
```

---

*Data:*

```
s <- c("AAAABDBBADCDCD", "AABDBBCCAACDAC", "AADBDDCBABDBCC")
r <- c("YYYYXXY", "YZZXXYY", "YYYZYXY")
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this @jay.sf, this is exactly what I needed! I really appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome @Aaron glad to have helped!